# Xam.Plugin.Media image folder empty

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement [jamesmontemagnos](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) Xam.Plugin.Media into my application to allow the user to upload images to the database however when the user clicks on the button to upload an image from their phone, all I see is a screen with the title 'Select a Photo' and the text 'Device Folders'.

As per the instructions I added the paths:

```
<external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
<external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
```

to a `file_paths.xml` but when the user clicks the button, this always seems null. I know with other implementations media uploads, you can copy an image to the phone by dragging and dropping it in and view it in the downloads folder.

I cannot seem to find which folder/ file this looks at in the code. Is there a specific way you have to add images to view them using this plugin?

EDIT:

Here are the current permissions I have in my AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

From reading the documentation, this is all I need. I don't seem to be getting any persmission error, just that no images/ folders are begin shown.

Comment: If you use the plugin, it is unnecessary to set the path of folder . It will open the photo library or camera in default .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT So if i were to drag and drop an image into the phone from file explorer, I won't be able to see it? Is the only way I can view images in emulator is to move them to the photo library?

Comment: Yes, this plugin has no API to set the path of image source :)

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT So with that said, what is the point in the `file_paths` file containing the external paths?

Comment: In your case , it is unnecessary .But if you implement it by other ways , it maybe will be important .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT So with this plugin, is it impossible for the user to upload an image they have downloaded from the internet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201414/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-jamess).